# Generating nested XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to use the FOR XML syntax to take a one table database and generate nested XML using an Azure SQL database.

My table looks like this

TASK Table

```
NAME    | ID | PARENT
School  |  0 | NULL
Math    |  1 |    0
CSC     |  2 |    0
Eng     |  3 |    0
HW      |  4 |    1
Quiz    |  5 |    1
HW      |  6 |    2
Quiz    |  7 |    2
HW      |  8 |    3
Quiz    |  9 |    3
Hw1     | 10 |    4
Hw2     | 11 |    4
```

This is what I want the XML to come out like

```xml
<Task name=School>  
   <Task name=Math>  
      <Task name=HW>  
         <Task name=Hw1>  
         <Task name=Hw2>  
      <Task name=Quiz>  
   <Task name=CSC>  
      <Task name=HW>  
      <Task name=Quiz>  
   <Task name=Eng>  
      <Task name=HW>  
      <Task name=Quiz>  
<\Task>
```

### -

---

## SOLUTION FROM @Mikael Eriksson

Go to www.SQLFiddle.com, select SQL Server 2012 in the top left corner.

Enter the following into the Schema panel on the left then 'Build Schema'

```
create table dbo.Task
(
  Name varchar(10),
  ID int,
  Parent int
);

insert into Task values
('School'  ,  0 , null),
('Math'    ,  1 ,    0),
('CSC'     ,  2 ,    0),
('Eng'     ,  3 ,    0),
('HW'      ,  4 ,    1),
('Quiz'    ,  5 ,    1),
('HW'      ,  6 ,    2),
('Quiz'    ,  7 ,    2),
('HW'      ,  8 ,    3),
('Quiz'    ,  9 ,    3),
('Hw1'     , 10 ,    4),
('Hw2'     , 11 ,    4);

go

create function dbo.GetTaskXML(@ParentID int) returns xml
as
begin
  return (
         select Name as [@name],
                (select dbo.GetTaskXML(ID))
         from dbo.Task
         where Parent = @ParentID or 
               (Parent is null and @ParentID is null)
         for xml path('Task'), type
         )
end
```

Remember to click on 'Build Schema', Once the schema is built, you can enter your query in the window on the right.

```
select dbo.GetTaskXML(null)
```

Now run query and the bottom window will return the XML results, thanks again Mikael

Comment: What does regex negation have to do with making nested XML?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but the answer to the question in the title is `WHERE column NOT REGEX s1 AND column NOT REGEX s2`.

Comment: ops, need to rename this

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Your output isn't valid xml. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your hierarchy is no deeper than 32 levels you can use a recursive scalar valued function that builds the XML.

```sql
create function dbo.GetTaskXML(@ParentID int) returns xml
as
begin
  return (
         select Name as [@name],
                (select dbo.GetTaskXML(ID))
         from dbo.Task
         where Parent = @ParentID or 
               (Parent is null and @ParentID is null)
         for xml path('Task'), type
         )
end
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a81c9/1)

Comment: Mikael, is it possible instead to return the xml using the names instead of Task for example <Task name=School> would be <School>?

Comment: @DevinGleasonLambert I don't think so. I let you know if I figure something out. Probably you need to build the XML using dynamic queries and then do that recursively will be pretty complicated and can not be done in a function because functions does not support dynamic SQL.